# In the profile, hyperlinks to Questions are double underlined

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Instead of using single underlines, question titles show double underlines when hovering them in the profile:

[image]

Apparently because the `.question-hyperlink:hover` has an extra:

```
border-bottom-color: #666;
border-bottom-style: dotted;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
```

… or something similar.

Comment: Hmm, notice when you move your cursor slightly under the question, the line goes back to one underline. Strange!

Answer (score 2):

The fix will be in the next production build.